# Showing index of duplicated values

Tags: excel

```
Tim     9/22/2015       Joe     9/22/2015       Joe      3          Tim      2
Frank   9/22/2015       Tim     9/22/2015       Tim      1          Frank   #N/A
Joe     9/21/2015       Karl    9/22/2015       Karl    #N/A        Joe      1
Tim     9/21/2015       Kim     9/22/2015       Kim     #N/A        Tim     #N/A
Luke    9/22/2015       James   9/22/2015       James   #N/A        Luke    #N/A
```

I am trying to get the index of duplicate name in the other table.
For example, the third table shows that Joe is located the third in the first table, Tim is First, no Karl, no Kim, and no James.

I used Match(name looking for, names in other table, 0).

The problem that Tim is available twice in table #1, but table #3 is showing only index 1.

I am trying to create a schedule that check and date overlapping. Any function other than Match?

Comment: {=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$A$9,ROW($A$2:$A$6)),ROW(1:1))} solved my problem

Comment: `=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($A$2:$A$6)/($A$2:$A$6=$A$9), ROW(1:1))` does away with having to confirm the formula with CSE.